# Poco X3 Pro 90Hz SetEdit setting not working

Tags: applications, settings, screen, android-11, miui

Poco X3 Pro ships with 60hz or 120hz screen settings and no 90hz (for optimal battery/performance preference like some other Xiaomi phones).

There are dozens of guides showing how to achieve 90hz without root and claimed to be working (people response in comment sections, etc.)

- [YouTube guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aVJyifR_TzU)
- [Reddit guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/PocoPhones/comments/jcpl9r/poco_x3_90hz_lock_no_root/)
- [More Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=poco%20x3%20pro%2090hz%20setedit)

All of them explain the same process using [SetEdit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=by4a.setedit22) app.

I did follow every step and rebooted the phone and tried with both 60hz and 120hz settings.

No matter what, it shows in the database `user_refresh_rate` is set to `90`, and yet the screen refresh rate is still at 120 (top left), tested with developer tools and testufo.

If the setting is overwritten by the app and saved into the database, how come it's not working?

[image]

Comment: Just curious, if you use SetEdit to change the value to 60, will it work as intended? Also, I found [a thread on XDA Forums](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/tutorial-how-to-set-the-screen-refresh-rate-to-90-hz.4266849/), but reading the posts, looks like the result is kind of mixed; some worked, but some didn't work. Possibly related to specific ROMs.

Comment: @AndrewT. I tried that with 60, no changes. It's interesting in that link I do not have step 3. on my Poco X3 Pro. I did however managed to clear system cached data with app called Activity Launcher and one thing I noticed the `user_refresh_rate` line was gone when I relaunched also freshly cleared SetEdit. I had to go to Display settings and toggle between 120 and 60 to add that line back, but changing it and rebooting still didn't work. Only difference I see from that forum post and mine is that my MiUI version is newer 12.5.4.